# Generic Chinese Tablet Stuck On "Erasing" Screen During Factory Reset

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, factory-reset, tablet

My generic Yuntab Q88 chinese tablet is stuck on the "Erasing" screen during factory reset. I don't know what to do because, I am a complete N00B at this. :/ What can I do? I can fix the Windows OS, but I can't fix the Android OS. I don't know how to fix this. I would really appricate Answers to my problem. The Android Version is 4.1.1 Kitkat.

[image: Android Erasing Screen]

Comment: If it's just a factory-reset, it should be safe to simply restart the device and try again (factory-reset doesn't really touch the system, it basically just removes user data).

Comment: @Izzy I have already tried that.

Comment: You could give [fastboot](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/fastboot/info) a try then. It has commands to perform a factory-reset as well (`fastboot erase cache` and `fastboot erase data`, see e.g. [Useful ADB and Fastboot Commands and How to Use them](http://techbeasts.com/2014/01/05/useful-adb-and-fastboot-commands-and-how-to-them/).

Comment: @Izzy, `fastboot` isn't really supported on generic Chinese tabs, and note the version no. in the question: **4.1.1 Kitkat**????

Comment: @Tamoghna Chowdhury So, what do I do now?